# why does a scala class in the worksheet with same name but different case as the worksheet cause an exception?

Tags: scala, scala-ide

When i have the following class i get an exception.

```
object rational {
  println("Welcome to the Scala worksheet")       //> Welcome to the Scala worksheet
  val x = new Rational(1,2)                       //> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Rational (wrong name: rational)
                                                  //|   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
                                                  //|   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassCond(ClassLoader.java:631)
                                                  //|   at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:615)
                                                  //|   at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:14
                                                  //| 1)
                                                  //|   at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:283)
                                                  //|   at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$000(URLClassLoader.java:58)
                                                  //|   at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:197)
                                                  //|   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
                                                  //|   at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:190)
                                                  //|   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:306)
                                                  //|   at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:301)
                                                  //|   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:247)
                                                  //|   at rational$$anonfun$main$1.apply$mcV$sp(rational.scala:3)
                                                  //|   at org.scalaide.worksheet.runtime.library.WorksheetSupport$$ano
                                                  //| Output exceeds cutoff limit.
}

class Rational (x:Int, y:Int) {
    def numer = x
    def denom = y

    def add(that:Rational) =
    new Rational (
            numer * that.denom + denom * that.numer, denom * that.denom
        )

        override def toString() = numer + "/" + denom
}
```

When i change the name of object rational to rationals everything is fine

Comment: I'm curious: Are you on Windows, OS X or Linux? To be more specific: Are you using a case-sensitive filesystem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is probably because of the type-insensitivity of the Windows file system.  This would get messed up in Java too.  The compiled .class files for the upper- and lower-case versions are indistinguishable and cannot both exist in the filesystem at the same time.

The `object rational` generates both a `rational$.class` and a `rational.class`.

The `class Rational` generates a `Rational.class`.  This appears to be being overwritten by `rational.class`.  When the JVM tries to read `Rational.class` it finds `rational.class`, sees that the content is wrong, and complains bitterly about having been led astray.